# Unexpected type inference in function interface

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 2.3.3.

```
{
    interface F { <T extends string = string>(x: T): T }
    const f: F = x => 1; // test failed: an error was expected
}{
    interface F<T extends string = string> { (x: T): T }
    const f: F = x => 1; // test passed: an error as expected
}
```

Could someone explain this behaviour, please?

Comment: I get errors in both cases.. because you can't assign a number to a string. A function of type F (in both cases) is expected to return a string.

Comment: @toskv, I get an error just in 2nd (TS 2.3.3). By the way, I simplified the example.

Comment: I tried it with the simplified one, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting

```
interface F<T extends string> { (x: T): T }
const f: F = x => 1; // Error: Generic argument was expected
```

Has got nothing to do with the fact that the function returns a `number`.

If you actually suppress the error with a type:

```
interface F<T extends string> { (x: T): T }
const f: F<any> = x => 1; // test failed: an error was expected
```

You can see *why* the *first case* isn't erroring. The generic is inferred to be `any` and hence `any => any` is easily satisfied by a function that `any => number` :

```
interface F { <T extends string = string>(x: T): T }
const f: F = x => 1; // No error cause `any` => `number` is valid for `any` => `any`
```